# How to rebrand an App in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Apple just forwarded me a nice legal letter from them-who-must-not-be-named and I was now wondering what the best way is to rebrand my App:

1) Without loosing my previous users == i.e. the old no-no app should become updated with the new rebranded one

2) Getting rid of all the references to the name which could bug them-who-must-not-be-named

My steps taken so far:

- Changed all the graphics
- went to my plist file and changed the Bundle display name

Now my questions:

- What happens if I change the Bundle identifier? Can I leave the old problematic name in there? Or will I get problems?
- What happens if I change the Bundle name?
- Will this have an effect on my old user's data structure, i.e. will their app crash if they the app looks in a folder with the old name of the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the bundle display name and the graphics should be enough, the bundle identifier isn't exposed to the user and must remain the same because otherwise its treated like a new app (and Application Loader will complain that the bundle identifier doesn't match).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bundle display name, but leave the bundle name allow, you can only update an app if the bundle name is the same.

The display name is what the user sees that is easy to change.